# Type of keyof variable as parameter

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have the following interface:

```js
interface ITest {
 a: number;
 b: string;
```

Now, I want a function, roughly like that:

```js
public filterByPropertyValue<T>(array: T[], key: keyof T, value: typeof ????) {
  return array.filter(e => e[key] === value)
}
```

More specifically, the following should *not* work:

```js
const array: ITest[] = [ {a: 1, b: 'some'}, {a: 2, b: 'value'}];

filterByPropertyValue<ITest>(array, 'a', 'abc') // as 'a' is of type number
filterByPropertyValue<ITest>(array, 'b', 15) // as 'b' is of type string
```

But the following should:

```js
const array: ITest[] = [ {a: 1, b: 'some'}, {a: 2, b: 'value'}];

filterByPropertyValue<ITest>(array, 'a', 1) // returns array[0]
filterByPropertyValue<ITest>(array, 'b', 'value') // returns array[1]
filterByPropertyValue<ITest>(array, 'b', 'foobar') // returns an empty array
```

I tried various combinations of `typeof` and `keyof` but I couldn't find a solution if `typeof` has to be used on a `keyof` variable.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WGY0JN) with two type parameters meet your needs?  Note that means you can't call the function by passing in `ITest` as a manually specified type argument (without also passing in the key as a type argument explicitly as well).  That also means you can't merely use `satisfies` since `[] satisfies ITest[]` will be of type `never[]`.  If it works for you with those caveats I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, please [edit] the question to clarify the requirements and/or leave a comment to tell me what I'm missing.

Comment: This is a actually a very good solution, and it works!
Background: It's actually going to be used as a pipe in angular, and somehow it still works there. If you write it up as answer, I'm happy to accept it.

Comment: @jcalz The empty array simply was laziness on my part, I will edit that. Passing empty arrays is not a requirement per se

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work you should add another [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `K` corresponding to the type of `K`, and then `value` can be given the [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `T[K]` meaning "the type of the value you get when you index into an object of type `T` with a key of type `K`":

```
function filterByPropertyValue<T, K extends keyof T>(array: T[], key: K, value: T[K]) {
  return array.filter(e => e[key] === value)
}
```

Now you get the desired behavior:

```
filterByPropertyValue(array, 'a', 15); // okay
filterByPropertyValue(array, 'a', 'abc') // error
filterByPropertyValue(array, 'b', 'abc') // okay
filterByPropertyValue(array, 'b', 15) // error
```

Note that I didn't manually specify the type arguments like `filterByPropertyValue<ITest, "a">(array, 'a', 15)`; the compiler inferred them for me.  TypeScript doesn't support *partial type argument inference* as requested in [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242), so your choices when calling this function are to either let the compiler infer both type arguments, or to specify both type arguments manually.  So you can't just call `filterByPropertyValue<ITest>(array, 'a', 15)` using this approach.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBUIGczIN4CwAUMsnAFzIgCuAtgEbQDcxp9lOUoA5i0QL7FiMaiARhgAexDIYwADaQoAIQCeABSiSADtDCqAanHnUIAHnQAaZAGlkEAB6QQAEyzIA1hFWSYydAB8ABRwUFBwqpToANoAutZekbbWAG7GplHRNrEAlPisyFAQYNRQMqHhqgB0corQQSgAvAH20YmxyI1dyGkmEDnEgkTECNI4ZGGUGNhgcZ3I0XhklACMAEwAzNbsyABEcPQIu8j81ksUyCsArNuU+xDH-LF8tUpqmjp6hukQIWHWAHI4ADrNcckxkAB6SHISQeCLCBRvDRaXRQfRGPp-KCA4G4w4AvLQ+xhSRQRF1FQoz7o75YiqA+gg5BAglEmFwhFEV7Qd6or6Y0zYxnMsFQmHQLTkohAA)